# How to Fix Entry Point Not Found

Tags: windows, adobe, entry-point, video-conversion, handbrake

I have been trying to convert video file for use in a project that I am working on. First, I tried to use adobe media encoder but I got this error when the program was loading:

> "Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point _Atomic_fetch_sub_4 could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCP.dll."

I then assuming it was an Adobe problem (because they updated recently). I tried HandBrake and got the exact same error.

Not sure what to do, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That file is part of **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package**.

What hides behind this name is the *Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable  Package* which can easily be downloaded on the Microsoft website as x86 or x64 edition:

32 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

64 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632

Also make sure you have the latest version of *Microsoft NET Framework*.. since Handbrake also needs it to function properly.